# Workflow required to perform lengthy ASP.NET task

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, twilio

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application that mimics a help desk system. The application works fine, but recently, they asked me to make it so that it can text message everyone in the system whenever a new help desk ticket is opened.

I am using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) to do this and it is working just fine. The only problem is, there are like 15 people in the system that should be getting this text message and when the ticket is submitted, the application takes about 15-20 seconds to repost from the submit. In the future, there could be more then 15 people, double that even.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to send these messages in the background, so that the page will come back from the submit right away. Here is my relevant code:

This is my main method I wrote for sending the text message. Its in a Utility class:

```
    public static string SendSms(string phoneNumber, string message)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + Constants.TwilioId + "/Messages.json");
        string postData = "From=" + Constants.TwilioFromNumber + "&To=+1" + phoneNumber + "&Body=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        string authorization = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Constants.TwilioId, Constants.TwilioAuthToken);
        string encodedAuthorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authorization));
        string credentials = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", encodedAuthorization);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = credentials;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        string responseString;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return responseString;
    }
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
public void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
    // This is more code here, but its irrelevant
    //

    var employees = new Employees();
    employees.GetAll();

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        string number = employee.CellPhoneAreaCode + employee.CellPhonePrefix +
                        employee.CellPhoneSuffix;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) && number.Length == 10)
        {
            Utility.SendSms(number, "A new Help Desk Ticket is in the System!");
        }
    }
}
```

The only other idea I can come up with is to create a WCF service, but that seemed like over kill. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: One approach could be to queue the messages in a simple database table and then have a Windows Service polling the table and sending the messages.

Comment: @David - Would it be better to create a Windows Service or would it be better to create a WCF service, where I can just pass it 10 numbers and the WCF service would queue them up and send it out?

Comment: I don't see how a WCF service would inherently make a difference.  If it's asynchronous then that would work, but any asynchronous approach would work.  For example, just kicking off a `Task` or calling an `async` method would be just as effective (and possibly much simpler).  The Windows Service idea is just to add a bit more manual queuing and handling of problems.  For example, if an `async` call fails in some way then re-trying could be a pain.  But if the Windows Service loop over the records fails it can just re-try on the next poll.

Comment: @David - Ok, I'm going to go with the Windows Service idea you suggested. You can make your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: did you get final solution? ***Twilio*** free ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any asynchronous approach should do the trick.  For example, using a `Task` or (if you're on .NET 4.5+) an `async` method.  (Remember to handle the asynchronous errors by supplying a callback with something like `.ContinueWith()` to examine the task for errors and respond accordingly.)

Meaningfully responding to errors in this case might be complex, though.  It sounds like the sort of operation where you want to keep re-trying in the event of a failure (with logging in case of constant failures), and definitely want to continue with the loop even if one message fails.  So something a little more manual might be in order.

For that I would recommend persisting the messages themselves to a simple database table from the application and continuing with the UI as you want.  Then have a separate application, such as a Windows Service, which periodically polls that database table and sends the messages in a simple loop over the records.

A good approach for something like this would be to keep a simple status flag on the message records.  Queued, sent, error (with an error message), etc.  The Windows Service can update the records as it sends the messages in the loop.  As any given message errors, just update that record and continue with the loop.  Re-try error-ed messages as appropriate.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I'm about to embark on tackling this type of functionality for e-mail in an app. I went looking for existing commercial or open source components that do this (as I'd like to avoid being the 1,298,726th developer to write one) but couldn't find one. Not to drift into a new question, but does anyone have one they've worked with before?

Comment: @JimMSDN: In most enterprise scenarios I've followed this same approach for sending emails for a few reasons.  1) It keeps a record of communications, which could come in handy later.  2) It abstracts the medium of the messaging, allowing users to configure different kinds of non-email communications without needing a lot of new code.  3) In high-volume communications even uncommon errors become common, and this offline sending approach handles errors very effectively.

Comment: I totally agree yours is the right approach - it is truly a "best practice".  Which would seem ripe for someone having tackled it for ASP.Net programmers "once and for all". Something akin to a sendmail, backed by a database, with a robust API to hook into and flexible output extensibility.  Perhaps, though, I'm now starting to write the specs for one here on SO...

Comment: @JimMSDN: Even if there was such a framework, I probably wouldn't use it.  The setup is simple enough that it can be written in as much time as it would take to download and set up a framework.  And in matters like these business rules and feature requirements tend to differ *very slightly* all over the place, so custom code is probably a better choice in most cases anyway.  Besides, if no such framework exists, you can always be the person to write one and put it on NuGet :)

Comment: @David - True that. I've already implemented your idea. It only took about an hour. I just created a new table called SmsMessage, added a few fields, then created a new Windows Service and created a subroutine to periodically check the table to see if there are any new unsent messages in the table.